# Directory.getFilesで数値順でのソートができません。

Tags: c#

```
dirNow = "C:\car";
fileNames[0] = "C:\car\1.txt";
fileNames[1] = "C:\car\2.txt";
fileNames[2] = "C:\car\3.txt";
fileNames[3] = "C:\car\10.txt";


string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(dirNow);
Array.Sort(fileNames);
foreach(string str in fileNames) Console.WriteLine(str);
Application.Exit();
```

結果

```
1.txt
10.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

理想

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
10.txt
```

Comment: タイトルを質問内容の目的にあわせて詳細化しました。

Comment: FYI: [エクスプローラのファイル順のように、自然順ソートで並び替える](http://wiki.dobon.net/index.php?.NET%A5%D7%A5%ED%A5%B0%A5%E9%A5%DF%A5%F3%A5%B0%B8%A6%B5%E6%2F111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WindowsであればStrCmpLogicalWを比較関数として使えば理想のソートが実現できます。

StrCmpLogicalW function (Windows) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

ファイル名は必ず数字だという前提ならば以下の様に書けます。

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var fileNames = new string[] {
            @"C:\car\1.txt",
            @"C:\car\2.txt",
            @"C:\car\3.txt",
            @"C:\car\10.txt"
        };
        //var dirNow = @"C:\car";
        //string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(dirNow);

        fileNames = fileNames.OrderBy(n => {
            int v = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(n), out v)) {
                return v;
            }
            return 9999999; // 数字で無いファイル名は一番後ろになる様に
        }).ToArray();

        foreach(string str in fileNames) {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```